# Spring Integration (SFTP): problem with downloading files from subdirectories

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am using Spring Integration version 5.4.4 in a Spring Boot application.
I need to get all the XML files from subdirectories under the "server_sftp" directory. For this I use SFTP Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter and SFTP Outbound Gateway with mget command. Unfortunately, the application only downloads files from the root directory ("server_sftp"), and does not download files from subdirectories.

Where do I go wrong?

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "downloadXmlFileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "300000"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpXmlFileMessageSource() {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template());
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("server_sftp/");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow xmlFilesReadingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(sftpXmlFileMessageSource(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(Sftp
                    .outboundGateway(template(), Command.MGET, "'server_sftp/*'")
                    .options(Option.RECURSIVE)
                    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                    .localDirectoryExpression("'../webapps/event_report_app-1.0/xmlFilesLocalDirectory/' + #remoteDirectory")
                    .localFilenameExpression("#remoteFileName.replaceFirst('sftpSource', 'localTarget')"))
            .channel("downloadXmlFileOutputChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public PollableChannel downloadXmlFileInputChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel downloadXmlFileOutputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

[directory structure on the sftp server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHHQX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [outbound gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) with a recursive MGET command to fetch the full tree.

> Using the mget Command
> mget retrieves multiple remote files based on a pattern and supports the following options:

> -P: Preserve the timestamps of the remote files.

> -R: Retrieve the entire directory tree recursively.

> -x: Throw an exception if no files match the pattern (otherwise, an empty list is returned).

> -D: Delete each remote file after successful transfer. If the transfer is ignored, the remote file is not deleted, because the FileExistsMode is IGNORE and the local file already exists.

> The message payload resulting from an mget operation is a List object (that is, a List of File objects, each representing a retrieved file).

Comment: please mre (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)